# WPF bind data grid combo box column programmatically to itemsource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my `datagrid`, one of columns is `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, where I'm trying to display different drop  down menu in every row. Easy task when creating combo box in XAML instead of doing it programatically. My problem is that I have no idea how to bind it properly. This is what I tried:

```
private DataGridComboBoxColumn CreateComboValueColumn(List<Elements> elements)
{
    DataGridComboBoxColumn column = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
    column.ItemsSource = elements;
    column.DisplayMemberPath = "Text";
    column.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
    column.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding("Value");
    return column;
}

public class Elements
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public List<ComboItem> ComboItems { get; set; }
}

public class ComboItem
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: why do you avoid xaml?

Comment: because I have dynamic amount of ``DataGrid``s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that adding binding from `style` works better than direct approach. This works:

```
private DataGridComboBoxColumn CreateComboValueColumn(List<Elements> elements)
{
    DataGridComboBoxColumn column = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();

    Style style = new Style(typeof(ComboBox));
    //set itemsource = {Binding ComboItems}
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("ComboItems")));
    column.DisplayMemberPath = "Text";
    column.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
    column.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding("Value");

    column.ElementStyle = style;
    column.EditingElementStyle = style;
    return column;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to think from above and read what you are doing.

```
    column.ItemsSource = elements;
```

That sets your column itemssource to a list of elements.

```
column.DisplayMemberPath = "Text";
```

It's not a member of Element so it won't show anything. You should set your column.ItemsSource to:

```
column.ItemsSource = elements[i].ComboItems
```

Being "i" the element you want to show.

Then if you want to show the text you should:

```
    column.DisplayMemberPath = "Text";
```

If you want the Id then just:

```
    column.DisplayMemberPath = "ID";
```

I wrote this without any editor and I think this is close to the answer you want, if I'm wrong comment this and I'll try to answer in a more accurate way.

Comment: you are right at pointing out that ``column.ItemsSource = elements[i].ComboItems``  should make it work. And it would, if I knew how to tell XML that ``i = column.row``

Comment: You get your items by XML ?